# Why my ctrl+semicolon was binded globally?

Tags: shortcut-keys, compiz, emacs, mint

My ctrl+semicolon key was binded to some sort of broken auto-complete program I guess. Whenever I am in typing mode(in terminal, editor, etc), my ctrl+semicolon comb was binded to this program. I have no idea what it is. Any help? Because I want to use this key combo in my eclipse, but I can't use it now.

[image]

[image]

I am new to linux and have 2 Mint 1 Ubuntu systems. All my systems have this problem, and they all have emacs(spacemacs) and compiz installed, but only 1 Mint system use the compiz.

Appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 10):

The problem is caused by an addon in fcitx named [Clipboard](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Clipboard). To disable it, simply open Fcitx Configuration -> Addon -> Clipboard, then either disable it or change its trigger key.

[Addon -> Clipboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cIdW.png)